# Registering an android app to receive certain file types

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, intentfilter

I would like my application to be able to receive vCards. Typically from an email attachment, but also files,etc. Unfortunately it does not show in the "Open with" / "Share with" menu.

This is the activity definition in the manifest:

```
     <activity
        android:name=".MyMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BROWSABLE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.vcf"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.vcf"/>
            <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.vcf"/>
            <data android:scheme="file" android:host="*" android:pathPattern=".*\\.vcf"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My test vCard email attachment has a `.vcf` file extension, and the email marks the mimetype as `text/vcard`. I've used a `*.*` mimetype for testing - clearly this would not be appropriate for production code.

The above code is cribbed from other stackoverflow questions, blog posts, etc.  I initially started with the following (both with a mimetype of `text/vcard` and then `*/*`:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: @sansa i think i'm doing everything in those answers? If it makes a difference, I'm testing with a tethered device - this a vcf test file and suitable emails.

Comment: Using file extensions isn't likely to work for email attachments or many other on-device uses. Go with your latter code snippet, replacing `SEND` with `VIEW`. If that works, refine the MIME type to `text/vcard`.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare - that appears to work. It appears, and selecting it does show my app's activity. It doesn't do anything with the vcard, but I think that is my internal mime-checking code.  The compiler gives me the AppLinkUrl warning which I should at least double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Web URLs and most on-device purposes, this should work with "Open With" sorts of options:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/vcard" />
    </intent-filter>
```

If you wanted to also support "Share With", you could try:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/vcard" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Note that how you get the content varies between those two actions:

- For `ACTION_VIEW`, it is `getData()` on your `Intent`
- For `ACTION_SEND`, look in the `EXTRA_STREAM` extra for a `Uri` or in the `EXTRA_TEXT` extra for the actual vCard text

Comment: Yes that fixed it - thanks. I've implemented both VIEW and SEND. The ACTION_VIEW returns a Uri in getData(). Now I just need to parse the vCard :-)